# How can Print Preview be called from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a page that is supposed to launch the Print Preview page onload.

I found this:

```
var OLECMDID = 7;
/* OLECMDID values:
* 6 - print
* 7 - print preview
* 1 - open window
* 4 - Save As
*/
var PROMPT = 1; // 2 DONTPROMPTUSER
var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID, PROMPT);
WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
```

But...

1. it does not work in FireFox.
2. it's kind of ugly.

Is there a better way for IE or a way that works for FireFox?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't, Print Preview is a feature of a browser, and therefore should be protected from being called by JavaScript as it would be a security risk.

That's why your example uses Active X, which bypasses the JavaScript security issues.

So instead use the print stylesheet that you already should have and show it for media=screen,print instead of media=print.

Read [Alist Apart: Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) for a good article on the subject of print stylesheets.

Comment: While this is a good article, it doesn't address his issue. We've got a client that doesn't want to teach their users to hit Ctrl+P or File -> Print so they want a print button on the screen.

Comment: If you have a Firefox extension or add-on that has access to the browser components and you need to launch the Print Preview, you can use: `PrintUtils.printPreview(PrintPreviewListener);`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you explain what makes print preview a security risk while print is not?  It seems to me there are many examples of existing browser-specific javascript.  What would be the security risk of a specific browser adding window.printPreview()?

Comment: Or, as of 2014, "Print preview" _is_ the print dialog in Chrome. I'm sure Firefox will follow suit.

Comment: You can manipulate the browser with JavaScript via the BOM - kind of hate that this is the only answer for this topic.

Comment: from being called by JavaScript as it would be a security risk.....really? How come you can call up print() from javascript?

Comment: well, Now in 2018, Yes you can! with `window.print();` it works for me.

Comment: @RajnishCoder no preview for firefox

Comment: @ManuelOrtiz In Firefox version `61.0.2 (64-bit)` Linux (fedora) it is working -just checked.

Comment: @RajnishCoder In Firefox 66 (Ubuntu) it opens the print dialog directly instead of the preview.

Comment: @PhoneixS can you explain what do you mean by **print dialog** and **preview**?

Comment: Unlike chrome, in 70.0.1 (64-bit) firefox, window.print() only brings up the print dialog box, still no preview.

Answer (score 31):

I think the best that's possible in cross-browser JavaScript is `window.print()`, which (in Firefox 3, for me) brings up the 'print' dialog and not the print preview dialog.

FYI, the *print dialog* is your computer's Print popup, what you get when you do Ctrl-p. The *print preview* is Firefox's own Preview window, and it has more options. It's what you get with Firefox Menu > Print...

Comment: In IE, this open print dialog, not PRINT PREVIEW

Comment: In Firefox 66 it also opens the print dialog instead of the preview.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done using javascript.
Say your html/aspx code goes this way:

```
<span>Main heading</span>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Contents"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label Text="Contractor Name" ID="lblCont" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<div id="forPrintPreview">
  <asp:Label Text="Company Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <asp:GridView runat="server">

      //GridView Content goes here

  </asp:GridView
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="PrintPreview();" value="Print Preview" />
```

Here on click of "Print Preview" button we will open a window with data for print.
Observe that 'forPrintPreview' is the id of a div.
The function for Print preview goes this way:

```
function PrintPreview() {
 var Contractor= $('span[id*="lblCont"]').html();
 printWindow = window.open("", "", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=600");
 printWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
 printWindow.document.write('<style type="text/css">@media print{.no-print, .no-print *{display: none !important;}</style>');
 printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
 printWindow.document.write('<div style="width:100%;text-align:right">');

  //Print and cancel button
 printWindow.document.write('<input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print" class="no-print" style="width:100px" onclick="window.print()" />');
 printWindow.document.write('<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" class="no-print"  style="width:100px" onclick="window.close()" />');

 printWindow.document.write('</div>');

 //You can include any data this way.
 printWindow.document.write('<table><tr><td>Contractor name:'+ Contractor +'</td></tr>you can include any info here</table');

 printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('forPrintPreview').innerHTML);
 //here 'forPrintPreview' is the id of the 'div' in current page(aspx).
 printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
 printWindow.document.close();
 printWindow.focus();
}
```

Observe that buttons 'print' and 'cancel' has the css class 'no-print', So these buttons will not appear in the print.