# Print HTML markup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to print some HTML markup with jQuery. There is a print button. When the print button is clicked, the click event creates some markup. I want to print those markup **on a printer**. How is it possible without any plugin?
The button

```
<a class="print-button" href="#" title="Print"></a>
```

The jquery:

```
$('.print-button').click(function (){
    var markup = '<html><head><title>TODO supply a title</title>... ...';
    // now print the markup
})
```

I just put a bit of the markup; because its too long. 
**Important: The markup contains also css in it. Some content has background image**

Comment: Print it on the screen? Or send it to an actual printer?

Comment: What do you mean by print it?

Comment: By _print_ you mean like _make a hardcopy_ or _print it on-screen_?

Comment: Print it on a printer. Just like the CTRL+P. But with customised markup. question edited

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this, not easily with css.

You can specify css for printing. For example

```
@media print
  {
  div.to_print {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
```

The trick here is to make everything. except what you want to print as hidden. This will guide you : [CSS - Print view - Hide all elements except one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511745/css-print-view-hide-all-elements-except-one-div) or [How to only show certain parts with CSS for Print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463796/how-to-only-show-certain-parts-with-css-for-print)

Them, in javascript, call the print function

```
window.print();
```

[How do I programatically call the "Print Preview" screen using Javascript or Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303705/how-do-i-programatically-call-the-print-preview-screen-using-javascript-or-jqu)

Comment: As an aside Imrul.H, I was able to provide 3 links to Stackoverflow with just a bit of searching. Your profile shows you are quite active on this site and have a good level of competence. How is it that you were not able to get some answers using basic searching?