# Show Print Preview Dialog in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, activex

I am working with IE8, in an environment where ActiveX is not allowed by group policy. I have a print bar I want to display with links that launch the Print and Print Preview dialogs. Is there an alternative to this code that doesn't require ActiveX?  I just need a script that will launch the Print Preview dialog.

All my users are using Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7 workstations.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function PrintPreview()
{
  var OLECMDID =  7;

  /* OLECMDID values:
  * 6 - print
  * 7 - print preview
  * 0 - open window
  * 4 - Save As
  */

  var PROMPT = 1; // 1 PROMPT USER 2 DON'T PROMPT USER
  var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
  WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID, PROMPT);
  WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
}   
</script>

<div class=HideDuringPrint id=divHideMe>
  <font size=2>
    <strong>
      <div style="float: left">
        <a href="javascript:window.print()">
          Print
        </a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:window.PrintPreview()">
          Preview
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style='clear: both;'></div>
    </strong>
  </font>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are out of luck if [tag:activex] is dlsabled - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973479. Although one answer from the aforementioned post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304845/637889) links to a jQuery plugin to do previews, if you don't mind adding jQuery to your site.