# Printpreview page not showing in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

By using `window.print()` in JavaScript, it does show a print preview in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I tested this command, and it is showing default browser print dialogue in IE and FF, what do you see in firefox ?

Comment: By giving that command, in FireFox it show normal print dialog box not an preview page. But in Google chrome it shows preview page by giving this same command.

Comment: thats default setting from browsers you cannot force a browser to show a dialogue on your will. Check this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript

Comment: ok thank you... then how to display printpreview page before print??

Comment: I am trying to print a popup window page. How to display a print preview page in popup window..

Answer (score 10):

In Firefox, this is not possible. Your only option is calling [`window.print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print), which only opens the Print dialog. Firefox extensions are able call [`PrintUtils.printPreview`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/files/browse/129161/file/chrome/content/overlay.xul#top), which opens the Print Preview window, but this API is not visible from the JavaScript code of webpages.

*Source: [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/948326)*