# window.print() difference between chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am currently setting up a webapplication which offers the user a way to print barcodes. For this, I am opening a print-window with `window.print()`.
In Google-Chrome this works fine, I am getting a preview which looks like that:

[image: Print-Preview in Google Chrome]

In Firefox, the same function opens a dialog looking like that:

[image: Printing in Firefox]

I know Firefox also offers a way to open a preview like in Google Chrome, but is this also possible by `JavaScript`?

I am already using CSS-Stylesheets with `print-media`. I have made separate style-sheets for this and didn't use the provided `@media queries`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript