# How can i handle different browser print dialogs?

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing

1. **Scenario**: I have a diagram-designer web application and need to print diagrams. In a custom shortcut (i "overwrite" the CTRL + P browser shortcut via
   `preventDefault()` )  i compute my print-page size and then call
   `window.print()`
2. **Problem**: In chrome appears the chrome-specific print dialog with preview of my page. That's fine... but firefox showing me the system
   (OS) print dialog without preview of my print-page. In firefox
   exists a specific print dialog with preview.(I found it at: Menu ->
   Print) How can i call this print dialog per js? Any alternative
   ideas how i can handle this case for all browsers?

Comment: There are so many different ways in which browsers might print, you should *not* have or try to enforce any specific expectations on that process. Even just overriding the keyboard shortcut is bound to fail in some browsers. The best you can do is provide a *print stylesheet* and let the browser handle the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Print Preview be called from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript)