# How to open IE11 print preview from button click ng2

Tags: angular

I want to call print preview from button click in angular 2. I need to support IE11 users. Chrome automatically open print preview on print but IE11 opens only print window.

In template:

```
<button (click)="print()">print</button>
```

In ts file:

```
print(){
  print() //lib.es6.d.ts
}
```

How can i open print preview in IE11?

Comment: Try [`window.print();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Comment: `window.print` opens only print window but not print preview

Comment: Apparently, you can't. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript read this thread.